# socketio namespace client "CONNECTION REFUSED"

Tags: socket.io

I have a problem with a weird socketio behavior, I don't want to post the whole context and problem. When I write:
Server side :

```
this.io.on('connection....
```

Client side:
    intance = io();

I have not connection problem everything is working. When I write
server side:

```
this.io.of('/data).on('connection....
```

client side:

```
instance = io('/data);
```

Everything goes work the client is popping "CONNECTION REFUSED". So I really don't understand. If anyone have an idea, out of context, of what it could be...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hint in the issues of the socket.io GitHub repos:

> [..] I think this problem should happen only when using a relative path without a host. [..]

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/812#issuecomment-74377946

I could confirm this issue with Socket.io 1.3.7.

This is how you connect to a namespace when serving from a port other than `port 80`:

**server.js**

```
import http from 'http';
import socketio from 'socket.io';

var server = http.createServer();
var io = socketio(server);

var nsp = io.of('/namespace');
```

**client.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var nsp = io('http://localhost:4000/namespace');
```

Comment: I don't remember how I solve this but yeah this is probably something like that :D